# Eureka - Add "None" Row when presenting PushRow

Tags: swift, uitableview, eureka-forms

PushRow in my project has disabled deselection option. Currently im trying to provide the option like adding an extra "None" Row to the presented View. How can it possible ?

```
private func createCustomPushRow(for field: JSON) {

    let typeId = field["field_type_id"].intValue
    let type = field["field_type"].stringValue
    var label = field["field_label"].stringValue
    let required = field["field_required"].boolValue

    var optionList: [String] = [String]()
    for customField in field["field_options"].arrayValue {
        optionList.append(customField["option_title"].stringValue)
    }

    label = required ? label + " *" : label
    form +++ Section(label)
        <<< PushRow<String>(String(typeId)) {
        $0.title = label.lowercased()
        $0.selectorTitle = "Pick " + label.lowercased()
        $0.options = optionList
        if required {
            $0.add(rule: RuleRequired())
            $0.validationOptions = .validatesOnChange
        }
        }.onPresent({ (_, to) in
            to.enableDeselection = false
        })
}
```

[image: Expected output]

Comment: This is unclear what you are asking. What kind of behaviour do you expect?

Comment: I need to add 1 more extra row (Named "None") on presenting the options in the pushrow. But the `RuleRequired()` validation in Eureka do not capture the  "None" ro as a value. Please refer the image with the question